# Background reading for parsing sloppy / quirky / "almost structured" data?

Tags: parsing, text-mining

I'm maintaining a program that needs to parse out data that is present in an "almost structured" form in text.  i.e. various programs that produce it use slightly different formats, it may have been printed out and OCR'd back in (yeah, I know) with errors, etc. so I need to use heuristics that guess how it was produced and apply different quirks modes, etc.  It's frustrating, because I'm somewhat familiar with the theory and practice of parsing if things are well behaved, and there are nice parsing frameworks etc. out there, but the unreliability of the data has led me to write some very sloppy ad-hoc code.  It's OK at the moment but I'm worried that as I expand it to process more variations and more complex data, things will get out of hand.  So my question is:

Since there are a fair number of existing commercial products that do related things ("quirks modes" in web browsers, error interpretation in compilers, even natural language processing and data mining, etc.) I'm sure some smart people have put thought into this, and tried to develop a theory, so what are the best sources for background reading on parsing unprincipled data in as principled a manner as possible?

I realize this is somewhat open-ended, but my problem is that I think I need more background to even know what the right questions to ask are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the choice between what you've proposed and fighting a hungry crocodile while covered in raw-beef-flavored marmalade and both hands tied behind my back, I'd choose the ...

Well, OK on a more serious note, if you have data that doesn't abide by the any "sane" structure, you have to study the data and find frequencies of quirks in it and correlate the data for the given context (i.e. how it was generated)

Print to OCR to get the data in is almost always going to lead to heart break.  The company I work for employs a veritable army of people who manually read such documents and hand "code" (i.e. enter by hand) the data for known problematic OCR scenarios, or documents our customers detect the original OCR failed on.

As for leveraging "Parsing Frameworks" these tend to expect data that will always follow the grammar rules you've laid out. The data you've described has no such guarantees.  If you go that route be prepared for unexpected - though not always obvious - failures.

By all means if there is any way possible to get the original data files, do so. Or if you can demand that those providing the data make their data come in a single well defined format, even better. (It might not be "YOUR" format, but at least it's a regular and predictable format you can convert from)